# How to launch an activity from another app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I dont know what I am doing wrong. I am trying to launch an activity of another app from current app.

Here is the code:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.second.package","com.second.package.SecondActivity")); 
    startActivity(intent); 

}
```

When I run this thing it says Application closed unexpectedly. What is wrong? Please help me.

**Succeded:** Just add :

```
android.intent.category.DEFAULT
```

to the activity in the manifest file.

Comment: do you have some more info in your logcat?

Comment: Sorry I am not testing it in emulator. Directly in device.

Comment: do u want to go from one activity to another activity?

Comment: if your device is hooked to a computer, you should still be able to see messages in logcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"); 
intent.setComponent(new   
ComponentName("com.second.package","com.second.package.SecondActivity")); 
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```